# References about market neutral portfolios that isolate unsystematic risk

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, hedging, reference-request, longshort, market-neutral

I am looking for references, information, backtests etc. about [market neutral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_neutral) portfolios that go *long the index* and *short stocks of that index with high unsystematic (idiosyncratic) risk*. The idea is to isolate and profit from the unsystematic risk.

Interestingly enough I couldn't find anything on this specific strategy but it might be that I have been looking in the wrong places or that this strategy doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

**EDIT:** See my answer here how the unsystematic risk of a single stock can be calculated: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/31497/12

Comment: Given that the performance is worst in the highest quintile of idiosyncratic risk and sort of OK in the other quintiles it would make sense to do what you say. I don't know of any specific funds doing this.